# Should I use は or が here?

Tags: は-and-が

> **先日、同級生は飼い犬を学校に連れてきました。**
>
> 彼の飼い犬はゴールデン・レトリバーで、すごく可愛かったです。
>
> 学生達に撫でられたり、甘えられたりすることがとても好きだったので、授業中に教室を走り回っていて、皆を迎えに行きました。
>
> 甘えん坊ですね～！

I posted that entry on Lang-8 and someone corrected my use of は to が
so

> 先日、同級生**は**飼い犬を学校に連れてきました。

to

> 先日、同級生**が**飼い犬を学校に連れてきました。

while other people said it was fine. I'm confused on which one I should use in this sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use が if this is the first sentence of your essay. By using が, you're introducing this 同級生 in the universe of discourse. See: [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/5010)

Using は sounds fairly awkward to me. In this case, 同級生は is like suddenly saying "*the* classmate". 同級生が is like "*a* classmate (of mine)".